# Grant permission on RDS read replica

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, sql-grant, read-replication

I have an RDS read replica instance. I have set the `read_only` flag to `0` to make any write operation possible. But where I am getting blocked is that the user in the read replica has only `SELECT` privilege. When I'm running grant privileges on the existing user it gives me error: `Access denied for user...`. How to grant?

Answer (score 0):

as your database's admin user, you can grant access to your other user using the GRANT command and FLUSH commands below. i'm using 'widgets' as the db name and 'widget_user' as the user you're granting access to, just for example:

```
db> GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,ALTER,INDEX ON widgets.* TO 'widget_user'@'%';
db> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

this GRANTs the widget_user the ability to select data, insert data, update data, delete data, drop tables/columns/indexes, alter tables/columns/indexes and create indexes on the widgets database.

you can find more detailed explanations and examples in this tutorial: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-grant.aspx